# Having issue with installing sdformat8-sdf on bionic 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am getting following message while trying to install Gazebo (ref link = `curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh`)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgazebo9-dev : Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.8.0-1~bionic) but 9.0.0+dfsg5-3ubuntu1+ppa2 is to be installed
                  Depends: gazebo9-common (= 9.8.0-1~bionic) but 9.0.0+dfsg5-3ubuntu1+ppa2 is to be installed
                  Depends: gazebo9-plugin-base (= 9.8.0-1~bionic)
 libsdformat8 : Depends: sdformat8-sdf (>= 8.1.0~pre1-1~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is installation order matters , (I should have followed )while installing gazebo and ROS?   As I tried this but it failed even to start gazebo if I install ROS first.   Then I tried way around that is first I installed Gazebo first and ROS then and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question consists of three steps:

1. Many packages related to Gazebo need *universe* pocket, so you have to enable it

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. Install Gazebo as you already tried

   ```
   curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
   ```
3. Then after installation you possibly get the following error message:

   > $ gazebo
   >   gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_common.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition10fuel_tools12ClientConfig12SetUserAgentERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

   it was [documented on their BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2448/problem-running-gazebo7), to apply the fix you need to run

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade libignition-math2
   ```